# Downvoting stupid simple questions

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I understand the reason of downvoting, and am aware of the downvote tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

But to what extent should this be applied? A lot of questions by new users are so simple that the first result on Google, or any {tech}-101 tutorial will provide an answer.

Should we downvote those? It doesn't make Stack Overflow feel very welcoming to newcomers, but might prevent it from becoming a forum for noobs/de facto replacement of Google.

Examples are questions where people clearly don't grasp the essentials of SQL, CSS, or the difference between server-side and client-side.

Comment: It depends.  By definition, if the first Google result adequately answers the question, then the question does not show any effort.  But on more arcane subjects, Googling requires knowing the right terms to feed it to get that answer (such as UIEditor vs UITypeEditor vs UIDesigner). In those cases, I am unlikely to DV - a person might just be new to that aspect.  It is becoming harder to Google sensibly as  MS/NET takes over commonplace words like 'generic'.

Comment: Well, if I google. Most of the times stack overflow comes out on top. Not allowing those questions might not make certain questions pop-up. Hard question.

Comment: @Plutonix, sometimes the first Google result may indeed *seem* to answer the question adequately. Yet, top Google ranking doesn't always indicate quality, or that what's suggested is a good idea (even if it works). For this reason, I'm not against LMGTFY questions sometimes, since they have the merits to expose the solution to some for of reviewing via the SO mechanisms (even if they're not perfect).

Comment: SO shouldn't be your first stop, it should be your last.

Comment: I generally don't downvote. I think I've only ever downvoted one question ever, and that was because it was a patently false answer. I think that this stuff will sort itself out, Darwin-style. A stupid question may beget a very good answer, or may be "stupid in the eye of the beholder" only (For example, an SQL expert would sneer at "What is a JOIN?", but a lot of folks don't know). I'm actually rather puzzled by how nasty and condescending folks can be here. Since this is a public forum, and is viewed by folks from all over, being a jerk here can be a huge career risk.

Answer (score 23):

I don't think simple questions are worthless. As long as the questions meets general standards, they can serve a useful purpose. This includes:

- They are not duplicates on SO. Many simple questions were asked before, and should be closed because they are in fact duplicates.
- They are on topic for SO. This includes that they are not just debugging help for trivial mistakes.
- They don't have any of the other common problems (opinion based, too broad, etc).

There is a difference between simple questions and bad questions. If simple questions meet all the requirements, they can still be good questions.

SO is used by people of various skill levels, so a topic that looks trivial to you can be useful to somebody else. That applies even to a single person when they explore areas they are not very familiar with. For example, I write a Python script about once a year, and do a lot of searching and documentation reading every time because I forgot the little I previously learned about it. When I do Google searches, very often SO questions show up as the very first search hit, and there is an answer that tells me exactly what I was looking for. While I could certainly have found the information elsewhere, SO is mostly the place with the best and most accessible information. In cases like this, the question was useful to me, even though it would be laughably easy for a Python expert.

IMHO, information being available elsewhere is not a reason to exclude it from SO. The problem these days is rarely that information does not exist. The bigger challenge is mostly that there's so much of it out there, that finding the right information can be very difficult for people. If SO can present this information in a form that people can find easily, it is current, correct, of high quality, and explained in language that most people understand, those questions and answers are useful.

I know people here sometimes find it unfair that simple questions and answers get the most upvotes, and posters can get a lot of rep for them. But maybe this really means that those simple questions help more people than the ones that might seem more interesting to some of us.

Comment: Good until we get to your last paragraph: The most prevalent problem with those simple questions, which makes people rage about them being upvote magnets, is that nearly all of them are obvious duplicates, they get really narrow partial answers with myriad unstated assumptions and dependencies (thus essentially useless for anyone but the asker, though not obviously so), and that crap displaces the complete and well-researched full answers mentioning all the gotchas.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of those. That's why I wanted to emphasize the difference between simple questions and bad questions. What you're describing are bad questions, and I'm all for down/close voting them. There are poorly written difficult questions as well. My main point was that questions shouldn't be downvoted **only** because they are simple, if they meet all other common requirements. Well, of course anybody is free to downvote what they want, but I don't think they deserve to be closed.