# Are beginners' questions welcome?

Tags: discussion

Suppose that a bright, curious beginner politely asks a C-programming question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25791255/1275653), not obviously an exact duplicate, regarding the mysteriously unpredictable address he has found in an uninitialized pointer.  Our beginner illustrates his question by including a clear example.  The question *in question* rapidly collects three upvotes and four answers but also (at this writing) *eight downvotes.*

Does StackOverflow expect such a beginner to get slammed in this way?  Or am I missing something?

I do not recall StackOverflow's being a hostile place when I joined.  If questions like the one in question got downvoted then, I do not remember it.  Is my memory faulty, or has something fundamentally changed?

Comment: My take is that people downvoting are doing it because searching for `uninitialized pointers` would result, for the `C` tag, in a lot of informations that would have answered his question. So lack of research effort would be the reason.

Comment: Take a look a the downvote tooltip.  Look at the first sentence fragment.  That's the one main consideration that you omitted from your list of criteria that questions need to meet.

Comment: *not obviously an exact duplicate.* "not obviously" is the problem here, please define it.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau:  Thanks, and of course I agree, because you are right.  I did search for `uninitialized pointers`, though, before posting my metaquestion.  The first ten hits did not seem to include anything that would clearly answer the beginner's question to a beginner's satisfaction.  And anyway, none of the eight downvoters seem to have commented on the question.  It *looks to me* like they just hit and ran.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: By "not obviously," I mean that if you type some of the question's keywords into the search box, like "uninitialized pointers," the first five or ten hits include nothing that would clearly answer the beginner's question to a beginner's satisfaction.

Comment: @thb, where did you read *clearly answering beginners' questions to their satisfaction* was a goal of this site?

Comment: @thb Really, because searching for the exact text of this title result in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273729/strange-behaviour-when-printing-pointers) being the second result (it would have been the top result had the question being discussed never been asked) and it looks like it has a fine answer to exactly the point raised here; certainly a much better answer than any I see on the new question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: One detects sarcasm.  If you have a point, then feel free just to make it.  The *answer* box is open for your use below.

Comment: @thb, so you want me to post *again*, after oh so many times, that **Stack Overflow is not meant to cater to beginners' needs, but instead to reward research and constructive questions?** ***Again?*** *In an answer?* Please look around before suggesting I violate the third normal form.

Comment: @Servy:  Your point is well taken, and I would be happy to be proved wrong.  Still, for my part, I tried searching for the exact text of this title.  Unless my search works differently than yours (which is possible for all I know), the first hit would seem to a beginner to be about some mysterious thing called "Cyclone."  You and I of course understand that the Cyclone answer does indeed also answer the beginner's question regarding C, but it looks to me unlikely that a beginner would grasp Cyclone's applicability.  Nevertheless, as I said, your point is well taken.

Comment: See also [Are beginner questions allowed on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152066) and [What is the proper way to approach SO as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downvoting stupid simple questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265565/downvoting-stupid-simple-questions), [How to deal with questions answerable with a simple web search?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251513/how-to-deal-with-questions-answerable-with-a-simple-web-search), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261721/why-do-people-downvote-elementary-questions, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270007/low-complexity-question-downvoted-for-a-reason, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252788/if-we-want-to-tackle-the-problem-of-question-quality-really-simple-questions-ne, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a question is clear, on topic, and not a duplicate, then It's welcome here, regardless of how easy it is or how much of a beginner question it is.

Comment: Not a duplicate is not really neccessary, not an obvious duplicate is.