# Attitude Toward Beginner Questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, but I've seen too many questions being asked and closed for stupid reasons. If they're closed for real reasons, that's fine, but they're not.

The question in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077186/basic-code-in-c-sharp-with-read-and-readline) (no pun intended) is a *very* common beginner issue. OP has read in a line with "read" and then calls readLine right after, which reads the newline, much to his dismay.

This was closed for being "too broad". Quotes heavily emphasized. This isn't too broad. It's a very common beginner issue with an obvious solution.

Can we close things for real reasons, or can we provide some sort of comment box when casting close votes? I don't have the permission to cast close votes on other peoples' questions, so maybe I don't understand the process.

Another issue is that experienced users come through and crap all over OP in the comments as if they're better than him. We could at least be gracious about it. The answer is obvious to us. If you're going to take the time to yell at him in the comments, then I think you should take the two sentences to give him the answer. A user with 36k rep had the audacity to tell a beginner to read the documentation!

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271177/are-beginners-questions-welcome) meta post clearly states that beginner questions are valid. Maybe OP in this situation is a duplicate, but I think the rest of my complaints still stand.

Comment: "too broad" is being (ab)used as the new 'minimal understanding required' close reason.

Comment: We need to add more close reasons instead of abusing them.

Comment: Dunno - I'm in two minds about this one.  Beginner, OK, but even a beginner might be expected to find online documentation on what those calls do and how they might explain the observed behaviour, (whatever that is).

Comment: I don't know about that. I'm sitting next to someone right now who just started his CS degree and is working on his hw. He has given up googling because he doesn't learn anything. I've shown him API pages and he doesn't learn from them. I remember asking my sister how to add a button in Java, and she got mad at me, but I didn't know how to do it. Now, I can help myself, and I can add a button with no problem with the help of the internet.

Comment: Well, CS degrees aren't for everyone, else what would be the point of having the degree? Similarly, Stack Exchange isn't for everyone: it's only for people who are able to use Stack Exchange.

Comment: All the real reasons went away, so we started closing things with crappy reasons.  "Too broad" refers to the breadth of the close reason, not the breadth of the question, though you wouldn't figure that out from looking at the text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I agree that the question is not too broad, and that some comments were unnecessary, but that question still is not very good.

> Why does the first read interfere with the second one?

That's pretty vague. How does it interfere? What's the expected vs. actual output? I'm not sure why people didn't close as "unclear what you're asking" and ask clarifying questions in the comments.

I've reopened the question. I'll leave it that way since it's answered (and the answer does clarify the question for me), but it wouldn't surprise me if it gets closed again.

> A user with 36k rep had the audacity to tell a beginner to read the documentation!

There's nothing wrong or audacious about that. New users can very well read the documentation before asking questions on Stack Overflow.

> Maybe OP in this situation is a duplicate...

It's got to be, right? I don't spend as much time in the C# tag as I should, so I can't find a canonical reference to close this as a duplicate of.

Comment: The Off Topic close reason "Questions seeking debugging help (..) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers" would also seem appropriate to me. That's really what's missing, the "specific problem" and "desired behavior".

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, that would work too.

Comment: @MillieSmith 1. It's not going to be clear to everyone unless the OP explains what he's trying to do. 2. It's still fine to suggest that people should read the documentation. 3. It probably wasn't closed as a duplicate to begin with because people couldn't immediately find a good original question.

Comment: I liked how Shog9 said that asking a question on Stack Overflow is the last thing you ever want to do; It should be a badge of shame.

Answer (score -6):

This issue is that in order to acquire a huge amount of reputation one must

1. have vast amounts of time on their hands. It's a known fact that acquiring points is about trawling through questions that are likely to be popular, but have not yet been answered and answer them before anyone else.
2. have some odd Obsessive Compulsive Disorder that motivates them to acquire fictional internet points

This means they must be quite anti-social and horrendously pedantic.  Their life *is* stackoverflow. The high-rep demographic has a bias towards unfriendly unhelpful people.  I usually find the most helpful people are around a few 100 or a couple of 1000 rep, since they have sufficient experience on the site to understand the community, while not actually caring about the points.

Some mega-rep users of course are genuinely helpful, most are not.

Comment: Maybe we just like sharing our knowledge!

Comment: +1 on this. While, the truth is somewhere in between, "Fictinal Internet Points" gave me a laugh. I've come to the same conclusion wondering how I can rack up xK's of points. When I attempt it, it all evens out. Then to find, some troll is downvoting old posts of mine because of a negative question I posted on meta. Go figure.

Comment: This is an awesome insightful answer.  Strange that it has net downvotes.

Comment: @DonHatch nah... nah it's really not "insightful", in any way. Actually, it reminds this one of the ramblings of underaged children, who don't like things not to go their preferred way. "samthebest" (did you reflect on how pedantic that actually is?) shows most of the flaws they are actually underlining in their answer, but I wouldn't think that self-observation is their *forte*.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier  How do you think I got 15K rep on here?  I was bored one week, and decided to prove my own point by answering questions on SO to optimise for future rep. I only spent time on questions that where (A) trivial to answer, (B) trivial to understand, (C) easy to copy and paste, (D) based on up-and-coming tech that would be mainstream in years to come.  Only took a few hours over the course of the week. Therefore rep = popular questions answered a long time ago. Rep != helpful and intelligent answers.

Comment: @samthebest Your account's acticity suggest that what you are saying is not true. You have answers well distributed over two years, and a gradual reputation increase. Any particular reason you would be misleading like this? Of course, the conclusion that reputation is not equal but rather highly correlated to helpful and intelligent answers is sound, but why that claim about a week's work?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Yes it's an exaggeration, but it is true that the majority of my points (and anyones, with the odd exception) are for the *popular* questions posted *early*. Many answers on SO that are upvoted the most are in fact wrong, or far worse than newer better thought out answers.  E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134882/undoing-a-git-rebase .  All I'm trying to point (pun intended) out is that the points system are far more ego-points than correctness-points.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier  Of course SO often ends up with the best answer at the top somehow, thanks to editing.  Fortunately this answer has been modified to include the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2389423/1586965 .  Also observe the number of upvotes - a single command `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, not even originating (pun intended) from the author, has resulted in more rep than 100s of highly detailed answers.  Face it, the original design of the points system is "highly inflationary" - to the point of total meaninglessness.