# What is a good question?

Tags: discussion

I really want to know what a good question is. I really, really do.

I am about to post two questions. The first is a question with positive voting from some random person. The second is a question I posted which was down voted. The first has no code, no evidence it isn't a homework assignment, very little detail, etc. My question has a full description of what I was trying to do, the code I was working with, and the question was specific.

So why is the first such a good question and my question trampled?

[What I think is a bad question, but got up voted.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31152196/)

[My question which I feel is a much, much better question, but was down voted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094693/how-do-you-position-divs-in-html5)

In addition to this, I found a question very similar to the first question above and I linked to it in an answer. I see no use in my answer getting down voted when I essentially supplied the same information as the other answers, I just didn't copy paste as much.

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of answering with a link to a duplicate question, either flag or vote to close. That is why your answer got downvoted.

Comment: There is no sense in doing the same thing I did but copy/pasting more content from the same question I was referencing. And I am fairly certain this is not a pile of fish website, but rather a means of learning to fish, and how to use google.

Comment: And I just got down voted on this question. How on God's green earth is this a bad question?

Comment: @Joel: You got downvoted, I suspect, because you failed to be properly respectful towards the experts who volunteer their time here.  You dared to complain, to question their judgement, and for that you must be punished.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit flippant, but here's a serious one: at a site like this, you really can't argue with or complain about the answers you receive.  You especially can't dispute the votes.  Don't worry too much about the votes your question gets.  What you really care is: did you get an answer?  If so, great.  If not, oh well, it's not as if this site owes you anything.  (My analogy is always: complaining that you didn't get the answer you wanted on a site like this is just like complaining that Santa Claus didn't give you what you asked for.)

Comment: Someone buys a car from a guy down the road. the guy selling says the car is in great shape and doesn't need anything but gas. the guy buying buys it and finds that it needs over $1000 in repairs soon after. the seller knew this. the buyer is not a mechanic and checked it as best as he could. the buyer questions the seller about it. the seller says he got the money and doesnt care, it is now the buyers problem. the buyer is not allowed to do anything but shell out the $1000 to repair the car. he doesnt have $1000. he has a lawn ornament and the seller has a stack of cash. thanks man. :)

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the specific question you think is good:

- You don't clearly indicate what you **want**. The little ASCII art is confusing.
- You throw vague terms like "Position them *properly*" and "I just want to build a *typical website*" without actually telling us what went wrong.
- You dumped your entire HTML and CSS code and asked us to "fix it" with very little context.
- You bursted and added long rants about the community in your question body. That's a sure recipe for more downvotes.

You should have a look in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure you know the guidelines for asking.

As for your "lost almost 100 rep over 2 days", that sounds suspicious, I can't see any trace of that in your profile. Are you sure?

Comment: I included the code I was working with. I asked how to align the main div's that are plainly visible in the code windows of both the html and css. And I drew a picture of what I was trying to do and get help with. I was proving that I tried at least to do it. A single person offered a reasonable attempt to help me. Everyone else just wanted to talk smack about my question. If you go to [link](http://freethecube.com/kt/) and play the game, download the new html and my game.js you will see that, with just a little help in the right direction, I totally conquered the problem I was having.

Comment: The old saying goes, "There is no such thing as a bad question," we all know there are bad questions. For someone that is a seasoned webmaster to vote down my question, it doesn't make sense. My question was not bad. It included a picture for crying out loud. I then included all the work for others to see that need help in just such a manner, because that is the type of person that I am. It doesn't help someone that is obviously trying to learn something to make them feel bad. That is why I made a new account. Joel is my name and I am here to learn.

Comment: Your question does not deserve -5 (I blame your rant for that), But it did deserve to be closed as either "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking", I read and reread your question, and I still can't understand exactly what it is that you want. The ASCII picture doesn't tell us anything. Try to include an actual image with Paint or http://draw.io.

Comment: Learn how to write better code. How does this random voting down on a whim help anyone learn? It doesn't. I refuse to stop learning. I will comb the internet. I will ask "stupid" questions. I will do whatever it takes to achieve the goal I am after. I drew a picture. How more clear and concise can someone get?

Comment: @Joel Let's continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82059/discussion-between-madara-uchiha-and-joel)

Comment: I am done with this. Someone once said, "How do you get the attention of the most high? By being the biggest pain in the ass." I know of another Joel, the president of stack exchange. I won't quit till I can talk to him. With your 68k rep why don't you get him to email me?

Comment: I am trying to help you. If you're going to be an ass about it, you can try helping yourself.

Comment: I am about to delete the work I did on the bad question. So it not harm me any further. It's a shame though. Someone, somewhere, could use that information.

Comment: @Joel *"How does this random voting down on a whim help anyone learn"* voting isn't there to help you learn or help you improve your question. It's there to rate the quality of the question. Comments and close votes are for helping you improve your question. don't take downvotes so seriously, just go with it. The moment you start ranting/complaining about it is when the situation is going to turn for the worst.

Comment: @Joel: It is absolutely useless for you to post a question here asking for guidance and then attack everyone who attempts to provide it. If you don't want feedback, don't ask for it. If you don't want to listen to that feedback, don't ask for it. If you just want to complain and argue, open a blog, open it for comments, and pontificate until your fingers bleed or your keyboard stops working. There is no *random voting* here, and accusing people of doing so is simply insulting and offensive.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked through the Help Center? Specifically the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section? There's a link there titled [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that goes into detail on how to ask good questions (I know, surprising).

Some of the important things:

- Don't include all your code. Include enough relevant code to reproduce the problem.
- Grammar, spelling, and punctuation are important.
- Write a specific title that summarizes your *specific* problem. Be sure you aren't suffering from the XY problem: asking how to do X when you're really trying to accomplish Y. "Rubber duck" debugging can help with this.
- Ask specific, isolated questions. Broad questions such as "how do I style a website with CSS?" or "how do I use a Model-View-Controller layout?" are off-topic and are not specific enough to be considered "good" questions.

Specific to your question, it looks like it's phrased in a way that is too broad, and your code doesn't seem to be isolated to the problem at hand.

And for what it's worth, I think the first question you linked is actually a bad question.

Comment: I feel my question was specific. How do I position the div's on the page? That really isn't any different to: How do I format output to the command line? The solution that was found was a  lot more complicated than it really needed to be, but it works very well. It was 3 div's, not 300. And I read that page. The biggest thing I have noticed is that in the 5 years I have used this site, what was considered a good question years ago, is a terrible question now, and people are far to eager to down vote when doing so only hurts the user, it doesn't help the site.

Comment: Rule of thumb: *respect the time of Stack Overflow's participants.*  That means using adequate English.  It means being brief, to the point and specific.  It means including enough information to make your question answerable.  It means bringing some effort to the table, not expecting Stack Overflow to do all of your work for you.  If you're still not sure, read [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html); it contains pretty much every way a new user can trip over a land mine.

Comment: I am not sure how my question doesn't fall right down that list for a seasoned webmaster to answer in just a few seconds. I am great at coding things, faster, less memory, readability. When it comes to the gui side of things, and the way that 50 million webmasters have to conform to 5 browsers is a bit tough sometimes. I do my best. Down voting because you don't have 30 seconds just seems a bit ridiculous. If you don't have time to answer then don't.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a community moderated community such as StackOverflow, the power of the people does go above the rules.

If the question is something people want to answer or think is a good question regardless of what StackOverflow defines as a "good question" people will upvote and answer it even if it is a bad question.

It's also relative to what community you're asking; the web-development society are in my experience much much harsher on bad questions as:
A) Most questions you can possibly have probably already has an answer
B) The documentation of web development is very extensive so you should be able to find what you want to know there.
C) Anyone can do a couple of tutorials and call themselves a web-designer, but in reality they have no clue what they're doing and want the community to do their work for them, and the community just have gotten fed up with this.

The C# community is much smaller and they are more friendly and tolerant. Exactly why I can only guess from generalization where smaller communities don't get exposed to bad questions, ask vampires and the likes as much as larger communities, along with the facts that they usually want to increase their community and being small means it's more personal and everyone kinda know each other.

#### So what is a good question?

The definition of a good question can be found on the tour page, but you may still score points on a bad question because people liked it even though it was off topic. Good questions can also get downvoted due to being duplicates or show great signs of lack of research.

In your case, neither question is a good question *(though the second one **is** better)*, but the communities following the tags in your questions are taking to it differently.

## EDIT:

Do note that I in no way am implying that the web-developers are unfriendly, they only generally keep to the rules in a stricter manner, and personally I think that's how it should be.

Comment: I had another account for nearly 5 years before this one. When I first started here, all my questions were taken seriously and reasonably. I took a couple years to do other things for the family and I came back recently and anything I asked was smashed to the ground. Every question since I came back. I am the same person. I ask the past questions in the exact same manner as I did the recent ones. Neither answer thus far has answered why my questions are so terrible now. They are the same, just on a different topic where I was asking about android apps then, I am asking about web stuff now.

Comment: Honestly, it's just been a few years. My rep dropped almost 100 points in 2 days. The questions were no different. I would really like to know why my questions are regarded as worthless garbage when I am asking questions in the same manner I have for years. Someone answer that please.

Comment: I can't answer for how SO historically have been, but it's still a matter of sub-communities within one community and their general opinions of things. When a topic has been thoroughly asked, the demand on your research before you ask increases. HTML, CSS and JavaScript have a huge question and answer rate so you really need to search it through.

Comment: @Joel Your rep has only dropped 10 points. You have never had 100 points on [so] http://stackoverflow.com/users/5057116/joel?tab=reputation

Comment: `The definition of a good question can be found on the tour page`

I just looked through the tour page but didn't find the definition.

Answer (score 4):

The day this question was posted, I was typing up an answer but got called away and didn't bother to save it.  Now today I came across [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299394/please-is-anything-going-to-be-done-about-the-pedantic-question-closers) and [its duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272328/attitude-toward-beginner-questions) and just feel compelled to answer again because I think they're related.

Others have already pointed to the help [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I'm going to add to it. There are a few points that make up a good question.

- **Be Specific**.  An analogy... A Person walks into a Doctor's office:

  - Patient:  Doctor, I'm in pain.
  - Doctor:  What's seems to be the problem?
  - Patient:  It hurts.
  - Doctor:  Where does it hurt?
  - Patient:  My body.
  - Doctor:  Where exactly on your body?
  - Patient:  My knee.
  - Doctor:  When did this start?
  - Patient:  Last week.
  - ...

  And so on.  Now, what if the patient was a bit more specific

  - Patient:  Doctor, last week I was running when suddenly I felt this sharp pain in my left knee and now it's difficult to walk.  The pain is very sharp but only occurs when I put weight on it.
  - Doctor:  Sounds like you managed to medical mumbo-jumbo your technical body term.  Let's get some x-rays.

  I don't know about anyone else, but I feel the latter scenario is far preferable -- especially in the realm of website posting communication.  The lesson here is give any and all specific information you can in your question.  ***While you may feel like you are wasting time typing it out, you will more than likely waste both your time and any potential helpers*** in the ensuing ping-pong communication if you just give, "I can't do techy thing.  It doesn't work." I try (not always successfully) to anticipate questions and give information that would answer them.  Said another way, try to write the question so that no one is going to ask you any counter-questions.  Their only response should be an answer.
- **Say what you are REALLY trying to accomplish.**  Avoid [bikeshedding.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange)  This can be tricky as I can see the case where you don't care if others feel what you are attempting is wrong.  However, that would mean you have enough experience to know this, which falls into the next point.  But in many cases, it's probably in your best interest to say *why*, from a big picture standpoint, you are asking the question.
- **Search, and research**.  This seems to be a bit of a hot topic lately.  The general question I see is why should posters be required to do research before asking a question?  It isn't technically required, although I wish it were.  Doing research *before* asking a question has so many benefits I don't know where to start, but I'll go with

  - **It saves YOU time.**  Understand that unless you are working on the cutting edge of technology, the question you have has almost certainly been asked and answered before.  There are 7 BILLION people on the planet.  Odds are at least one other person has had the same issue as you are having.  It pays to at least make a cursory attempt with Google to search and see if something comes up.  I rarely have to give more than 4 words in Google to find what I'm looking for.  Average case is maybe two attempts to get something relevant on the first page.  That typically means about 30 seconds max to have an answer, maybe more if it's *really* obscure (eg your software fails only on every other blue moon).  Simply posting a question will take at least that, and that doesn't mean getting an answer.  If you give good info, probably longer to type it.  If you don't give good info (see previous point about being specific), you'll eat up tons of time explaining what you really meant.  Getting the answer may take anywhere from 1 to ∞ minutes.
  - **It will improve your research abilities.**  I'm going to guess that most people do other things in life other than program.  Buying stuff, playing sports, etc, etc.  They all can benefit from being able to do research.  Like anything, research takes practice.  The more you research, the better you will (probably) get at it.
  - **It suggests a level of understanding.**  Part of the point to research before posting is that you will ***include your findings*** if you still need to ask a question.  "I found X but it didn't work because Y," gives more insight into getting you an answer.

**TL;DR** -- Research.  Be specific.  Research.  Research more.  Post your findings if you end up asking the question.

Asking a good question can be more difficult than answering it.  But that's because it's far easier to answer a good question than a bad one.

Answer (score -3):

[This is, I admit, more of a comment on another answer than it is an answer to the original question.  But it's way too long for a comment.]

In another answer, @MadConan offered a hypothetical "non-specific" conversation in a doctor's office:

> Patient: Doctor, I'm in pain.
>   Doctor: What's seems to be the problem?
>   Patient: It hurts.
>   Doctor: Where does it hurt?
>   Patient: My body.
>   Doctor: Where exactly on your body?
>   Patient: My knee.
>   ...

And then, by contrast, he offered a "more specific" alternative:

> Patient: Doctor, last week I was running when suddenly I felt this sharp pain in my left knee and now it's difficult to walk. The pain is very sharp but only occurs when I put weight on it.
>   Doctor: Sounds like...

And, finally, he offered the opinion that

> I don't know about anyone else, but I feel the latter scenario is far preferable...

So I'll bite, and be the "anyone else", and offer a dissenting opinion.

The former, "nonspecific" conversation is just like the ones that happen every single day in every doctor's office anywhere in the world.  It's a perfectly normal Q&A.  The latter, "efficient" conversation, on the other hand, has never happened and probably never will.  It's so implausible, so unlikely to succeed, that I can't agree it's preferable.

To see why, let's first revisit an old joke.  A hungry Stack Overflow regular walks into a Burger King.  Wanting to be "efficient", he launches into the following dialog, which doesn't quite play out as intended:

Regular: I'd like a Whopper, to go, hold the tomatoes.
Clerk: You'd like a Whopper?
Regular: Yes, please, to go.
Clerk: You want everything on that?
Regular: Hold the tomatoes.
Clerk: For here or to go?
Regular (exasperated): To go.

So the attempt to be "efficient" backfires, and all the information has to be transmitted twice, because the initial presentation was too fast, and in the wrong order, and before the clerk was ready to receive it.

This is far from a perfect analogy, but there are several things to take away from it:

1. The regular broke the rules.  He didn't follow the script.  (That's kind of the lesson we keep trying to teach the newbies.)
2. There was a wide gulf in sophistication.  The regular wanted to be savvy, and tried to present a large amount of information at once.  The clerk was being mundane and slow, one thing at a time.  On Stack Overflow the roles are usually reversed, but any time you have a large "impedance mismatch" between sender and receiver, you're unlikely to be able to transfer a large amount of information, in one step function, without some ringing.
3. It's actually okay for there to be some Q&A.  There's no reputation bonus for the smallest number of back-and-forth interactions before a question is answered.

My point is that while it's certainly important for posters to provide all the relevant information, we really don't want them providing lots of irrelevant information.  (That's why we ask them to strip their code down to just the bit that has the problem, rather than presenting their whole program.)  But -- and this is a very big, very important "but" -- beginners who ask questions are *never* going to be able to do a perfect job discriminating between relevant and irrelevant information.  They're always going to post irrelevant information, and they're always going to leave out relevant information.  Expecting them to always do a perfect job discriminating relevancy is tantamount to asking them to know so much about the subject that they'd be able to answer all their own questions, which would kind of defeat the whole point of setting up a Q&A website in the first place.

Exasperating as it certainly can be for questioners to keep asking malformed questions that we can't necessarily immediately answer, that phenomenon is: inevitable.  It's human nature.  It's going to happen, and it's going to keep happening.  It's never going to get any better.  Attempts to "fix" this problem, by erecting all sorts of unnatural rules that new posters are expected to follow, or by browbeating the ones who don't, are not going to work.

Comment: "The latter .. has never happened and probably never will."  It has and does all the time.  As a tiny example:   My first position out of college was performance testing web servers.  Any defect without detailed information was immediately rejected and closed.  I learned very fast to put in as much detail as possible or be ignored.  I've personally been involved in and witnessed many, many other instances of the "never happens" conversation.  I'm betting I'm not the only one.