# How to deal with questions that ask about complete basics?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

How do I deal with questions that ask about complete basics?

Where answer could be found by the OP after a two minutes of googling, reading the first paragraph of the first book or having at least basic knowledge of the area. For example, like this one:

- [Sitecore - Add Web Form For Marketer from codebehind using MVC.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26419128) ([screenshot for < 10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpXqz.png))
- *How to add a button to the form in Visual Studio* (theoretical).

I can't find a proper flag or review decision, neither under `Flag` link or in my review queue tool. There is nothing about "Too basic", "Too obvious", etc.

If I catch such a question in the *First Posts* queue, there is no vote-to-close option, only *No Action Needed*, *I'm Done* and *Skip*. I don't want to skip this question, and it certainly needs some actions. Out of the actions available, I can flag this question. What reason should I pick in this case?

This is:

- a basic,
- effort-less,
- tutorial-seeking

question. But, it isn't:

- very low quality,
- a duplicate of another,
- off-topic or opinion-based,
- too broad or unclear, what is asked.

It is simply a very, very basic question, that is answered in many books and webpages, but not on Stack Overflow (too basic), so I can't mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: I usually flag'm as "too broad", and comment with a link to the docs.

Comment: @Cerbrus But when someone asks a question like "How to add a button to the form in Visual Studio", then this question is certainly not to broad. It is quite specific, yet we don't want it here, because it is way to basic. Shouldn't we have any extra option for such situation? I'm asking, because I had some wrong flags issued lately, including "too broad".

Comment: No research effort = -1

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I can't use -1 / it is not enough, if I catch such question in the review queue. After -1 I'd have to use "Skip" in this case. Which isn't the way, I'd like to handle such question. Any other options?

Comment: You could also use: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think, I'm convinced. Again, question like "How to add a button to the form in Visual Studio" isn't neither recommendation seeking nor it isn't primairly opinion-based. This is a stright question, that can get a stright answer, only it is very, very basic and was answered million times in thousands of books and Internet sites. It wasn't, however, asked on SO (because it is too basic), so I can't flag it as duplicate. It is simply... very basic question, that shouldn't be asked for this particular reason.

Comment: Those questions are basically looking for a tutorial.
Look, I'm trying to give you some options that would be reasonable close-vote reasons. If you don't want to hear them, why ask for them in the first place?

Comment: @trejder I tend to open the question in a new tab, down-vote and close the tab. Then back in the review tab I vote to close the question as suggested by Cerbrus.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think, you get me wrong. All your attempts to solve my question are carefully read by me and upvoted. I only express my doubts, that I think this isn't enough solution. What's wrong about that?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå What reason do you choose, when voting to close, after downvoting question in a separate tab?

Comment: Please, review my edited question and eventually propose some consise answer, so we can dig-out it out of the comments.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265565/downvoting-stupid-simple-questions.

Comment: If the questions do not meet any of the close reasons, they should stay open. There's no rule against basic questions. Often these kinds of questions are duplicates (a lot of basic questions have already been asked and answered), are unclear, too broad, or one of the other close reasons you list. But for the relatively rare ones where none of that applies, they can stay open, and be answered.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Care to make that into an answer?

Comment: This is the big problem; if it's not read the first sentence you find on any search engine basic then you have a good chance at finding a duplicate and getting it closed in a singl vote. If it is read the first sentence then it's actually quit difficult to find a duplicate target...

Comment: This question is about complete basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is: <...> tutorial-seeking

So, close vote as Off Topic:
*"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: ... or too broad

Comment: ... or custom reason

Comment: Note that the mods don't tend to appreciate custom flags in scenarios where either one of the other flags would apply, or where it's a case of "I  don't like it but none of the flag reasons really explain why". One should make sure there's a compelling reason to use a custom flag before going that route.

Comment: @sphanley note that a custom close reason is not a custom flag.  Once you have 3k rep, you can write anything you want as a custom reason.  "Your question appears to be off topic because it is about if you should wear shoes while coding." - that is not a flag when enter in the close question wizard.

Comment: I disagree completely. If it's this much effort to find a reason to close a question, you should be asking yourself if it needs to be closed at all.

Comment: The situation doesn't seem to require that much effort, though.

Comment: @chris or you should be askimg if we need different close reasons.

Comment: @Yakk I disagree. Why do people want "too basic" questions closed in the first place? The general feeling seems to be that if these questions are answered, then someone will be getting help that they don't 'deserve'. Rubbish! Everyone needs help sometimes. Stands to reason that some people will need help right at the start of their programming journey, when their level of knowledge is zero. Instead of scaring them away ("your question is too dumb!") we should be thinking about how we can give them a good experience and draw them into the community so that they become contributors themselves.

Answer (score 47):

Something to remember is that not everything needs to be flagged for moderation. When you mouse over the "downvote" arrow, the hover text reaads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it  is unclear or not useful.

Lack of research effort sounds like the heart of what you're describing, so if there's nothing else fundamentally wrong with the posts that warrants the attention of a moderator, downvoting it is the community's way of sinking posts which add no value.

Answer (score 33):

A question that is **not**

- very low quality,
- a duplicate of another,
- off-topic or opinion-based,
- too broad or unclear what is asked

(and not asking for a tutorial)

is **on topic** on Stack Overflow, however simple and obvious the answer might be to anyone with any programming knowledge.

The action you should take is to **downvote** the question (for lack of research effort), and then answer it should you choose to do so.

Remember, link only answers are not good enough, so if you are going to link to the documentation (which is reasonable) explain why this bit of the documentation is useful, and perhaps say (nicely) the OP might want to read more of the docs in future.

---

In answer to a comment below, here is the *off topic* flag criteria page;

[image: Flag as off topic reasons]

"Too basic" is not a flag as off topic reason; so why would you think that such a question was off topic?

Comment: So if I ask how to make a cupcake, it is on topic?  Stack overflow is a website for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Yakk it depends. I'm not sure if I could make a cupcake in DirectX/C++.

Comment: @Yakk The third bullet point should cover cupcakes.

Comment: @worldofjr So, can a question be so basic as too be off topic?

Comment: @Yakk I couldn't post a picture as a comment, so I've added to my answer.

Comment: By this argument, `How do I print text to the console in a console app` is a valid question. There _has_ to be some minimum level of understanding, even if it's "has bothered to read even a single document on the topic they're asking about"

Comment: @Basic So what would you flag such a question as (assuming it's **not**;
    very low quality,
    a duplicate of another,
    off-topic or opinion-based,
    too broad or unclear what is asked).

Comment: @Basic, since this site is for "professional" and "enthusiast" programmers, this basic question is on-topic, again this is my (not-so-humble) opinion and 2 cents

Comment: @worldofjr If it's one of those you list, the current flags work fine. The example I gave should be flagged as [Lacks minimal understanding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/156755). Unfortunately, since that option is no longer available, I have no idea. I think the current stance at SO is to allow questions with no value for professional or enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Basic, plus one should clearly and uambigouusly draw the line between "interesting for professionals" and "minimal understanding" and just "plain elitism", i would say this is too broad, again if you think you can manage the line here, it would be great

Comment: @NikosM. I think we'd both agree it's not something a professional would need to ask//have answered. As to enthusiasts? If they're enthusiastic, they're willing to try to google for a solution (since they're enthusiastic). It's not a site for those who are unwilling to put in even minimal effort. Maybe that sounds elitist. It wasn't meant to. We need to improve the signal to noise ratio around here

Comment: @Basic, to be clear, i think i understand what is meant in your comemnt (and the kind of programers or future programmers that are the target group). Of course one can always take online courses in programming and basic programming if needed.

Comment: I don't know if you remember everything.com? it was an attempt to create a collection of knowledge about everything. Some users thought that meant "everything worth knowing", others thought it meant "everything including what I had for breakfast". everything.com died under the weight of useless info. everything2.com is still going and has a fairly eclectic range of useful info. I think the dividing line should be something like "could a user learn this by reading an introductory page/tutorial on a language" (or programming concepts in general - conditionals/loops/etc).

Comment: @Basic, i think stackexhange (the whole network) is a kind of "everything.com", since it has (or creates) sub-networks for almost everything (basic programming, hacking, sports, karate, religion, philosophy, parenting, family, politics, higher mathematics, advanced and basic physics, it even has an are 51 for crying out loud :))

Answer (score 18):

***There is nothing wrong with basic questions!***

Just because a question has an answer that it is basic (to you) or simple (to you) or obvious (to you) that does not mean that it should be closed or left unanswered.

The journey from novice programmer to expert is long, and it's easy to forget, when you are a long way down that path, how little you knew at the beginning.

If someone has taken the time to type up a well formatted, understandable question, and that question hasn't already been asked and answered elsewhere on the site, then your response should be to give it the best answer you possibly can (remembering that the person who asked it doesn't have as much programming experience as you, so will probably benefit from additional explanation) and then move on.

As an added incentive, questions that are "basic" often receive a lot of attention, and good answers to "basic" questions often receive many upvotes because they are solving a problem that a lot of people have. So you should answer these questions because doing so is beneficial to the person asking, beneficial to the site as a whole, and beneficial to you personally.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if asking about, how to place a button on a form is a question, that fits into your "journey from novice programmer to expert". Neither, I'm not convinced, if Stack Overflow is a place for such questions. And I'm asking only about this kind of questions...

Comment: @trejder Obviously for many people, it fits in right at the start of that journey. Don't forget that one of the things a programmer needs to learn is how to find programming help. Just knowing what to Google is a skill that has to be learned. Maybe I'm particularly sensitive to this because I've just spent two weekends teaching complete novice programmers (people who have no idea what a command line is, some of whom have hardly used a computer at all) how to code. But it's easy to forget how little people know when they are just starting out.

Answer (score 10):

Given how many people use SO for this exact purpose I don't understand the repeated belief this is ever going to stop.  Maybe a better use of one's time than coming up with new ways to tell people to go away is to either point them to a resource or to simply move along. I'll also point out -- and not for the first time -- that it was this exact same attitude towards the "noob" that wiped out experts-exchange so many years ago.  Now quick, downvote me so I'll learn my lesson!

Comment: Indeed, "people are getting undeserved help on the Interwebs!!!" is a philosophy which can only tie its adherents into fits of frustration.

Comment: I didn't realise that it was a *noob* that took down experts-exchange. I thought it was an ill thought out web address (when you remove the hyphen).

Comment: Experts-Exchange was wiped out because there were no quality standards enforced, and because any moron could be a self-proclaimed "expert". We avoid that by actually enforcing standards here, and by having each and every question and answer evaluated by the users. If we drive away the quality of "noob" that can't do basic research before posting here, so be it. SO is supposed to be the last resort for finding an answer, **after you've exhausted every other means**.

Comment: Unfortunately or luckily most programming-related web searches lead to Stackoverflow. So it can hardly be the last resort :-D

Comment: @Ken: you say that, but it directly contradicts the originally stated (albeit intentionally so ambitious it could never be finished) goal of StackOverflow: to have answers to *all* programming questions. Not all programming questions that cannot be answered by other means. Fact is, there are a lot of people on StackOverflow who are offended by easy questions. This is fine until there's something that you think is difficult but is easy to someone else, and they close your question. SO must synthesize different views of what it's for, and closing everything we don't like doesn't achieve that

Comment: @Steve: No, you're wrong. StackOverflow expects you to put forth effort to solve the problem yourself *before* asking here. Visit the help center, or take the tour. There are close reasons for too broad, unclear, asking debugging questions without code, etc. This was never intended to be the dumping ground for all trivial or low effort questions about code; it's intended to be a knowledge base, but not of noise and clutter related to "How do I add 1 + 1 in <this> language?" questions. SO expects posters to put in the effort to find a solution first before asking here.

Comment: I'm wrong that Joel Spolsky said that when he co-founded the site, or I'm wrong that SO must synthesize views other than yours of what constitutes clutter? ;-) It's quite true that SO expects some work before asking a question. That is work to write a good question, not work to ensure that there isn't some obscure little page somewhere else on the internet, or handwritten manuscript in a library in a monastery in Albania, that would answer it by other means. It is quite simply a gross exaggeration to say that SO is the site of last resort. I'd rank it behind the manual and nothing else.

Comment: Anyway, if I were to go through questions and close-vote everything to which I can find an answer from a source other than SO, that would be vandalism as I hope you'd agree. There's a medium between extremes, of course, but the extreme you stated as your position is evil, bad and wrong!

Answer (score 8):

When I start using something new to me, I tend to not start with tutorial, but start just doing something. Of course as a result I immediately have a number of questions. Some of them require thinking to compare with my previous experience and results in "if I were creating this technology, I would done that in this way" and that usually works after all (not with Apple way, though, but whatever). But many of them are just simple questions, which doesn't ever deserve thinking, because I just had to read docs about that - and in this case I just go to Google.

In 99.9% cases first link in search results is SO question, which is really basic (like the ones you describing in your post), have good and straightforward answers, both question and answer hugely upvoted, and immediately solves my needs. That usually takes about 30 seconds, and I just continue my work without switching off context.

You know, I personally would never ask *that* questions. I would continue to Google, RTFM, and maybe even books in hard cases - but after all, I have a good fundamental knowledge to just google for basic questions I need for my immediate needs.

But I understand that a really big part of my use of SO is finding for basic answers for basic questions - which somebody really should have asked.

So, my opinion - basic questions just fit into SO format; if we don't have answers to these basic questions here, on SO - then these questions should be asked.

Answer (score 7):

If it's not a duplicate then leave it alone and let someone who can learn something by answering it.  A simple question--something that a beginner might be able to answer--isn't hurting anything and can be very helpful to a lot of people.

Also if someone asked it, someone else will want to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the idea from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/258026#258026) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason#comment106932_274630): **Lacks minimal effort** close reason!

> After all, it's what we are all talking about implicitly - why not make it explicit. Also, it doesn't sound so rude as it does not suggest that OP is stupid ("understanding") - it's just saying they could do better.

Comment: upvoted, but i disagree